# Dynamic Contact Form With Mulitple Recipients

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

We are using Contact Form 7 and in our Wordpress site. In the functions.php file we have the code below. Only 1 recipient seems to be receiving it the submissions. Are we incorrectly listing the multiple emails?

Thank you!!!!!

```
add_action(‘wpcf7_before_send_mail’, ‘dynamic_email_recipient’, 99999, 3);
function dynamic_email_recipient($contact_form, $abort, $submission)
{

$properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
$recipient = $properties['mail']['recipient'];

if (!isset($_POST['interest_choice'])) {
    return;
}

$email_type = $_POST['interest_choice'];

switch ($email_type) {
    case 'Partner with VPP':
        $recipient = 'email1@abc.com, email2@abc.com, email3@abc.com, email4@abc.com';`


I tried this but the site went down so most likely incorrect:

$recipient = 'email1@abc.com', 'email2@abc.com', 'email3@abc.com', 'email4@abc.com';
```